# How to convert semi-structured xml data into table and to color-code selected cells using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml data is semi-structured. I need to transfer textual and numeric data into the table. Plus I need to compare numeric data and color-code the matches if they satisfy 2 tests. I wonder if its achievable given the xml input is not highly structured.
My input data looks as follows:

```
<DIV>
 <ul>
  <li>CC(fr3.1)<br/> : AX(en1.1)</li>
  <li>(fr4.1)<br/> : AX(en1.1)</li>
  <li>AA(fr1.1)<br/> : BX(en2.1)</li>
  <li>CC(fr3.1)<br/> : BX(en2.1)</li>

  <li>DD(fr1.2)<br/> : (en1.2)</li>
  <li>EE(fr2.2)<br/> : FX(en6.2)</li>
  <li>FF(fr3.2)<br/> : (en3.2)</li>
  <li>GG(fr4.2)<br/> : DX(en4.2)</li>
  <li>HH(fr5.2)<br/> : EX(en5.2)</li>
 </ul>
</DIV>
```

The numeric data prefixed with 'fr' should go into the columns on the same row-level. So should data prefixed with 'en' go into the rows below. The number after the dot means that the textual data and its accompanying number in the parentheses belong to one and the same <seg> element in the output. The data from each <seg> should be arranged into separate tables. E.g. the input above would require 2 separate tables. Color-coding should take into account 2 tests: 1) if the numeric value from 'fr' row is the same as the corresponding value in the cell below from the 'en' row, then both the cells should be assigned the background color yellow (#ffff00); 2) if the numeric data in the xml input had no textual data, then the cell into which goes the numeric value that had no textual value in the input, should be assigned the background color red (#ff0000).

All in all, the HTML output should look as follows:

[image: Table]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is 'group' your data by the 'seg' number, which in your case is the value after the full stop, but before the last parenthesis. In XSLT 1.0 this is done by a technique known as [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). To do this, you first define a key to group the **li** elements by this value, like so.

```
<xsl:key name="type" match="li" use="substring-before(substring-after(text(), '.'), ')')" />
```

Then, you would match the **li** elements who occur first in the group for their relevant 'seg' number. This is done like so:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
   <xsl:variable name="seg" select="substring-before(substring-after(text(), '.'), ')')"/>
   <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', $seg)[1])">
```

This gives you your two distinct 'seg' groups.

For each group, you would then first get all the text nodes for the 'fr' text (assuming they are always the first ones that appear).

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('type', $seg)/text()[1]">
   <xsl:with-param name="cellnumber" select="1"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Note, I am also passing in the cell number, as this will be used to get the text in the other 'cell' for comparison.

And to get the 'en' text, is similar

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('type', $seg)/text()[2]">
   <xsl:with-param name="cellnumber" select="2"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Within the templates that matches these, you would then use some string manipulation to get the value you need (in XSLT 2.0 you could use the power of regular expressions to simplify things)

To get the first two letters (e.g. 'CC' or 'AX', etc), if they exist, you would do this

```
 <xsl:variable name="text" select="translate(substring-before(., '('), ' :', '')"/>
```

And to get the number, you would do this (this assumes you will only ever have 'fr' or 'en')

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="translate(substring-after(., '('), 'fren)', '')"/>
```

Now, to get the text in the other cell, you can do make use of the **cellnumber** passed in as the parameter.

```
<xsl:variable name="othercell" select="../text()[3 - $cellnumber]"/>
```

You can then extract the number in a similar manner, and use it in the comparison to get the colour:

```
  <xsl:variable name="colour">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$text = ''">FF0000</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$number = $othernumber">FFFFFF</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>FFFF00</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="type" match="li" use="substring-before(substring-after(text(), '.'), ')')"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//li"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="li">
      <xsl:variable name="seg" select="substring-before(substring-after(text(), '.'), ')')"/>
      <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', $seg)[1])">
         <h1 id="{$seg}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$seg"/>
         </h1>
         <table>
         <tr>
            <td>fr</td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type', $seg)/text()[1]">
               <xsl:with-param name="cellnumber" select="1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>en</td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type', $seg)/text()[2]">
               <xsl:with-param name="cellnumber" select="2"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </tr>
         </table>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:param name="cellnumber"/>

      <xsl:variable name="text" select="translate(substring-before(., '('), ' :', '')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="number" select="translate(substring-after(., '('), 'fren)', '')"/>

      <xsl:variable name="othercell" select="../text()[3 - $cellnumber]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="othernumber" select="translate(substring-after($othercell, '('), 'fren)', '')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="colour">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$text = ''">FF0000</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$number = $othernumber">FFFFFF</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>FFFF00</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <td style="background-color:#{$colour}">
         <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<h1 id="1">1</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>fr</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">3.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FF0000">4.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">1.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">3.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>en</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">1.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">1.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">2.1</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">2.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1 id="2">2</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>fr</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">1.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">2.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">3.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">4.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">5.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>en</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FF0000">1.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFF00">6.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FF0000">3.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">4.2</td>
        <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF">5.2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This doesn't 'quite' match up with your diagram, but you diagram doesn't quite tie up with how you have described how the colouring should work.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation, I've got the logic. Yet the output is not quite what I needed. 1st, I need the 2-letter prefixes be stripped in order to compare the numeric values alone. They also need to be arranged in rows to be comparable. 2nd, with your code I still cannot figure out how to build in the tests for colour-coding. I've noticed I mixed it up in the previous output example, hence you found it misleading. So, I'm adding the visual to illustrate what it should look like in the html output. Btw, if the xml input is very long, I assume your code would take ages to write...

Comment: I have re-jigged my answer to give something much closer to what you were expecting, I hope!

Comment: Thanks, this is superb! And apologies for a mix-up in my question, which might have been the only challenge.